# German Pre-fixes - Do they carry meaning?

Tags: prefix

I frequently come across words like `versprechen, erhalten, beliefern`. Because my vocabulary is limited, i can detect that the verbs `sprechen, halten and liefern` were spoken but i do not know what `ver-sprechen, er-halten and be-liefern` mean. Is there a `definite meaning of prefixes like these?`

How should i tackle this topic of prefixes so that when a verb with a prefix is spoken, i can guess/know what it would mean. Thanks

Comment: yes, there is but hardly can it be framed in a catchy manner. You can either accept up to 5 different concepts or you have to settle for a REALLY vague and abstract idea that each prefix kind of sort of represents... they are an integral part of German and you will likely spend some time on them.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Explanation of the prefix "er"](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6195/explanation-of-the-prefix-er) and [The prefix "ver-" and its meaning](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/3894/the-prefix-ver-and-its-meaning?rq=1) and [What are the origin & possible meanings of the ver- prefix?](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/2279/what-are-the-origin-possible-meanings-of-the-ver-prefix?rq=1) and [Reference work on prefixes, suffixes, etc.](http://german.stackexchange.com/questions/6353/reference-work-on-prefixes-suffixes-etc?rq=1).

Comment: Has there been a software update? The suggestions in the "Related" sidebar are getting better.

Answer (score 1):

there is a difference, and you cant say its general this (...) way.

for example `sprechen` means `talking`. but `versprechen` means `promise` or `to misspeak`

you have to learn them, there isnt a general rule i guess